# error at return response.meta[ ]

Tags: python, scrapy

I was running the below code and the code seems to have some problems.
what is shown below is not my entire code, I will post the rest of the code if someone asks me for it:

```
from threading import Thread 
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urlparse
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "scrapy"
    def get_url():
        url = raw_input('Enter the url of your website (including the http)')
        return url      
    start_url = str(get_url())
    def parse(self,response):
         return response



def get_depth():
    scrapies = MySpider()
    response= Request(scrapies.start_url)
    return response.meta['depth']
```

The error occurs at `return response.meta['depth']`. the error message doesn't have a specific content, it just says `key error: depth`, so I am not sure how to fix that. Does this mean that the `depth` is not appropriate argument to the `meta`?

thanks..

Comment: It means there is no key 'depth' in the dictionary.

Comment: I realized that when I just put `return response.meta` instead of `return response.meta['depth']`, it returns an empty set. is this the problem with scrapy or problem with my code?

Comment: It most likely means that there are no meta tags in the document. You need to detect and deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Yield to call get_depth and pass the meta values along with it. See the example below.

yield Request(url=someurl, callback=self.get_depth,meta={'key': value}, )